# Html bootstrap alert auto close difficulties

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have do some research online and find out that the below code can auto hide an alert:

```
        function Testing()
        {
            $("#alertmsg").show();
            $("#alertmsg").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
                $("#alertmsg").alert('close');
            });
        }
```

I have created a button to trigger the alert message:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="Testing()">Apply</button>
```

The problem is, it can only done once. What I mean is, when the page is loaded, and I click the button and the alert message will come out. And it will auto hide after a few seconds. After that when I press the button again in attempt to let the alert message come out, it fail already. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Replace `.alert('close')` with `.hide()` as `.alert('close')` removes the element than hides it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts) using `alert('close')` removes the alert object from the DOM so you wont be able to display it again unless you re-add the html for the alert to the DOM.

If you are using `show()` to display your alert you may be better off using `hide()` to hide it rather than `alert("close")` so your code would become

```
    function Testing()
    {
        $("#alertmsg").show();
        $("#alertmsg").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
            $("#alertmsg").hide();
        });
    }
```